# Fetch PFInstallation By User id or some unique id :Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

Can i get PFInstallation object by userd id so that i can subscribe channel for that installation. [PFInstallation currentInstallation] give only istallation for that device .I wanted to get installation for other device by user id.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what I did is I subscribed the user to his own channel with `user_` in front of it. Channels cannot start with numbers, and some objectIds do.

```
currentInstallation.channels = ["global", "user_" + PFUser.currentUser().objectId]
```

Then you can send the push notification to the user based on their objectId by sending it to channel `user_objectId`.

In this occasion, the users are subscribed to documents. The question asker was storing the subscribed channels to the Installation object. This is what I recommended he do.

Create a new table called: `Subscriptions`

Each row should contain: `user: UserPointer` and `document: DocumentPointer`

When a user subscribes to a document, then you need to create a new row for that user/document combo.

Then when sending a push, rather than sending a push to the documentId channel, you send it to all the users that are subscribed to that document. The code for that is below.

```
//Get all the users that are subscribed to docId
var userQuery = new Parse.Query("Subscriptions");
userQuery.equalTo("document", docId);
userQuery.limit(1000);
userQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {
        //results contains at most 1000 subscribed users
        var userIdChannels = [];
        //Extract out the userIds from results
        for(var i = 0; i < userIds.length; ++i) {
            userIdChannels.push("user_" + results[i].get("user").id);
        }
        //Now send a push notification to all the subscribed users
        var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        pushQuery.equalTo('channels', userIdChannels);

        Parse.Push.send({
            where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
            data: {
                alert: "Document updated"
            }
        },{
            success: function() {
                // Push was successful
            },
            error: function(error) {
                throw "Error sending push";
            }
        });

    }, error: function(error) {
         throw "Error getting subscribed users";
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually my scenario is when single user has multiple device .So suppose he subscribe to channel A on iPhone and he login to iPad(but not subsctibe to channel A in iPad) So how we can send push notification to both device on basis of Channel A.

Comment: If the user is the same, then both devices will be subscribed to `user_objecId`.

Comment: ya but then we need to go to iPad and subscribe for that channel right.I want to auto subscribe in iPad once user subscribe a channel in iPhone.